# accumulated average sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, window-functions

I want to get the cumulative average of the following data per month.

EJ

```
date     val  acum
20221229  1    1
20221230  8    4.5
20221231  3    4
20230101  7    7
20230101  4    5.5
```

Code:

```
BEGIN var_out = SELECT FCURR,
    date,
    val,
    SUM(SUM(val)) over (order by date asc) AS acum
    FROM 
(SELECT 
    val
    FROM table
    WHERE "KURST" ='M')
GROUP BY  date,val
ORDER BY 3 DESC; END
```

Comment: Please tag yours question with the database you are running : mysql, oracle, postgresql…?

Comment: I see you've tagged it SQL Server but the syntax doesn't look like that is correct. `BEGIN var_out = SELECT ` is not valid SQL Serer syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *seem to* be looking for a window average over months partitions.

In SQL Server, assuming a table like `mytable(dt, val)`:

```
select dt, val,
   avg(1.0 * val) over(
        partition by year(dt), month(dt) 
        order by dt
    ) running_monthly_avg
from mytable
where kurst = 'M'
```

This averages the value in monthly partitions that are sorted by date. Typically, the first row of the month averages over itself only, while the last row averages the whole month.

From the sample data and results I don’t see the need for `group by` in the query, so I removed it.

Here is **[a DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VnDyp_gV)**:

| dt | val | running_monthly_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-29 | 1 | 1.000000 |
| 2022-12-30 | 8 | 4.500000 |
| 2022-12-31 | 3 | 4.000000 |
| 2023-01-01 | 7 | 7.000000 |
| 2023-01-02 | 4 | 5.500000 |

Comment: I already tried with : 
 avg(val) over(
        partition by year(date), month(ate) order by date) AS acum                  but it returns "0" in all records

Comment: @KLM: if your averages are below `1`, that could be because of integer division. I added a `1.0` multiplier in the average to force the proper numeric conversion. I also added a fiddle to my answer where you can see the query in action.